# Debugging the issues on Megiddo's algorithm

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have done code for the algorithm to obtain the Optimal Basis but as I calculate the optimal solution $Xb=B^{-1}b$, I only get the correct value for some of the variables. For some variables, $Xb_i$ is not equal to the $X_i$, where $X_i$ is the result of some LP solver, used in Megiddo's algorithm.

What can be the possible issue?

In my problem, $Xb$ need not be always positive. Can this be a problem in the implementation of the algorithm?

Comment: Try reading the original paper: http://theory.stanford.edu/~megiddo/pdf/bases.pdf.

Comment: I have seen that but finding it a bit difficult to understand and then code the algorithm. It will be great if one or two examples can be there for the using the same algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps you might be more likely to get a useful answer if you edit your question to ask about a single specific aspect of the algorithm that you don't understand.  It's up to you.

Comment: @D.W. can you please have a look at it now?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't see any question, here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks for pointing towards it. I think now it is clear.

Comment: @ParikshitPareek It's clear what your question is, but it seems unanswerable. Debugging your code is off-ropic everywhere on the Stack Exchange network and it seems that you basically want us to do that, but without even knowing what the code is!

Comment: @DavidRicherby the main question of mine is that how can it be possible to get few variables correct and some wrong from the same code? Also, whether not having the limits as $Xb>=0$ creates any problem with the algorithm in finding Optimal Basis? –